# Printing Path stored as variable to text document-Python

Tags: python-3.x, pyqt4, pycharm

I'm working on a python project where a user is prompted to select a file, the file path is returned and stored as a variable, then printed to a new text document. I've tried converting the variable to string and other tricks, but I mostly get similar results to:

```
    <PyQt4.QtGui.QLineEdit object at 0x0000000004DB2318>
```

When I view the text document I created with the printed variable. The path seems to be returned correctly when I view it in the inputbox I saved it to. Below are the methods I'm using to get/save the file name and then print the variable to the text document. Any recommendations or help would be greatly appreciated!

```
def browse_folder_two(self):
    filename = QtGui.QFileDialog.getOpenFileName(caption='Open File', directory='.')
    self.lineEditImageDestination.setText(filename)

def file_save(self):
    with open("Output.txt", "w") as text_file:
        print((str(self.lineEditXMLSource)), file=text_file)
        sys.exit()
```

Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

So I ended up figuring it out. The print line should have been self.lineEditXMLSource.text() instead of the str